# wordpress remove_query_arg not working

Tags: php, wordpress

Using latest Wordpress version, I am testing the add_query_arg() function.

I want to change this:

```
https://www.amazon.com/booktitle/dp/XX1234/ref=as_li_ss_tl?ie=UTF8&
qid=1468851514&sr=8-1&keywords=there&tag=mytag-20#navbar
```

to this

```
https://www.amazon.com/booktitle/dp/XX1234/ref=as_li_ss_tl?ie=UTF8&qid=1468851514&sr=8-1&keywords=there&tag=thenewtag-20#navbar
```

(changing the 'tag' parameter in the query)

So I use the WP function `add_query_arg()` thusly:

```
$url = 'https://www.amazon.com/booktitle/dp/XX1234/ref=as_li_ss_tl?ie=UTF8&qid=1468851514&sr=8-1&keywords=there&tag=mytag-20#navbar';
$newtag = "thenewtag";
$url1= add_query_tag('tag', false, $url);  // should remove the 'tag' key/value from the query
$url2 = add_query_tag('tag', $newtag, $url1);  // should add the new 'tag' value to the query
echo $url1 ;  // returns the original $url
echo $url2 ;  // returns 'https://www.amazon.com/booktitle/dp/XX1234/ref=as_li_ss_tl?ie=UTF8&qid=1468851514&sr=8-1&keywords=there&tag=mytag-20&tag=thenewtag#navbar'
```

The first tag parameter (value = 'mytag') is still there, and the second tag parameter (value = 'thenewtag') is added (like it should be).

Why doesn't `add_query_tag` remove the first tag parameter, as the docs say that it should.

Note that I have tried the WP r`emove_query_arg()` function, but it just calls `add_query_tag()`, so I just used `add_query_arg()` with the 'remove' syntax.

Also that esc_url (to prevent XSS) is not used here (I take care of that later/elsewhere).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$url1 = add_query_tag('amp;tag', false, $url);
echo $url1;
```